# (Pages) Keyboard shortcut to change colour of selected text

Tags: macos, pages, text, iwork

Is it possible to make a shortcut in Pages to change just the selected text (not entire paragraph or part with the same style) to any colour of choice?

I am trying to achieve some sort of a quick highlighting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is Apple support document named
[Add a highlight effect to text in Pages on Mac](https://support.apple.com/et-ee/guide/pages/taned4110e43/mac). There is detailed information how to do it but essence of it boils down to this:

> If you often add colors behind text, you can [create a character style](https://support.apple.com/et-ee/guide/pages/tan7aaef6765/11.2/mac/1.0)
> that uses a particular text background color. Then you can choose that
> style from the Character Styles pop-up menu to highlight selected text
> with that color. You can also [create a keyboard shortcut](https://support.apple.com/et-ee/guide/pages/tanb8c18c476/11.2/mac/1.0) to apply the
> character style.

Comment: Thanks, I cannot believe I have missed it! 

Answer (score 1):

Pages has a default menu-item for highlighting text which can be accessed by selecting the text and pressing ⇧⌘H (Shift + Command + H). It's also present in the Insert Menu

[image: Highlight Text]

Comment: Yes, thanks, but this feature uses yellow background for highlighting - my point was whether you can, e.g., make your own shortcut (and choose your own colour/background) or maybe directly change the definition of "Highlight" to make the selected text, e.g., green.